# Application of calculus in kinematics Newton 2nd law

Tags: calculus, integration, physics, kinematics

As we all know it the Newton's second law of motion describes the relationship between force and acceleration of a body as  diectly proportional. Now lets say a body in motion and is of mass of 9kg and its acceleration is $a($t)=-9$t$. we are to find its displacement $y$ as a funtion of time $t$.

I know from calculus that when you integrate acceleration you get velocity and when you integrate velocity you get displacement.
i followed suit but i want to see if this a valid way of going by it or... perphaps its wrong

Comment: Yes that's right, but note that you need boundary/initial values to be able to actually pin down $y$ as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y(t)$ be the displacement on time $ t$. Then

$$a=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=-9t$$
after a first integration, we find

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\int_{t_0}^t(-9u)du$$

$$=\Bigl[-\frac{9u^2}{2}\Bigr]_{t_0}^t$$
$$=-\frac{9t^2}{2}+V_0$$

the second integration gives

$$y(t)=\int_{t_0}^t(-\frac 92u^2+V_0)du$$

$$=\Bigl[-\frac{3}{2}u^3+V_0u\Bigr]_{t_0}^t$$

$$=-\frac 32 t^3+V_0t+Y_0$$

$Y_0$ and $ V_0$ are respectively the position and the velocity at $t=0$.

Comment: Will there be a need to add constants of integration?

Comment: @BoatengKwasiAyisi It depends on your initial conditions.

Comment: So if no intial conditions were given ??

Comment: @BoatengKwasiAyisi I added the constants.

Comment: Good you really like substitution I guess